# How do I calculate a Bayesian Posterior Distribution from an Exponential Prior and Sample Data

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference, posterior, exponential-distribution

I have a dataset where each observation is a length of time (e.g. 50 days, 70 days, 105 days) and I am trying to utilize Bayesian statistics to calculate a posterior distribution in light of new data. Based on my research it seems like an exponential distribution is the right type of distribution for this type of data. I used python to fit an exponential distribution to my data and got a lambda of 93.

My question: what is the process of generating a posterior distribution from my prior in light of new data. For example, let's say I generate three new observations of 10 days, 30 days, and 40 days - how would I use bayes' rule to update my prior and generate a new posterior distribution? Thanks!

Comment: What is your original prior?  You need one for your first step in order to generate a posterior.  Note that it can't just be something like $\lambda = 93$, because that's what your posterior will be too.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your comment, I am thinking I don't have a firm enough grasp on the concepts yet. I was thinking I would create an informative prior based on my dataset, where that prior is an exponential distribution with λ=93. Then, I would update that prior with new data as it comes in. Can you help me understand where I am going wrong with my reasoning? Thanks.